How to get amplify authenticator callback with Angular?
I use aws authenticator to sign in and signup.
<amplify-authenticator>

            <ng-template amplifySlot="header">
              <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; padding: var(--amplify-space-large); text-align: center; background-color: #1E293B; box-shadow: 5px 3px 5px 1px black" >
                <img
                  class="gara-image"
                  alt="Gara logo"
                  src="https://d35dakp7lbtcub.cloudfront.net/console/logo-dark.svg"
                />
              </div>
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template
              amplifySlot="authenticated"
              let-user="user"
              let-signOut="signOut"
            >
              <h1>Welcome {{ user.username }}!</h1>
              <button (click)="signOut()">Sign Out</button>
            </ng-template>
          </amplify-authenticator>

I want to achive something very simple. I want when the user is login to call a function so I can know that he is login and I can do the rest of the flow.
I don't find any callback possible.
I use the V6 and tried many things without success.
The only solution I see is to loop each second and use const { username, userId, signInDetails } = await getCurrentUser();  but i don't want to have loop on the function. I want trigger the function only when the login is done.
Please how could I do ?
Thank you.
